# Powershell_how to get a section id of HTML DOM?

Tags: html, powershell

I'm new to Powershell.
I'm curretly trying to get the url of both "a href" and "img src" which are defined in specific section id(id="YY").

The code below is the sample of html

```
<div id="XX">
  <section id="AA">
  </section>
    # many sections here
  <section id="YY">
    <a href="https://XYZ.jpg">
      <img src = "https://ABC.jpg">
    </a>
  </section>
    # many sections here
</div>
```

I managed to get the nodes of "div id="XX" by
$elements = $html.getElementById("XX").childNodes.
However I'm not sure how to get the childNode which holds the target "section id="YY".
Is there any way to get it or resources I can look up to?

Comment: How about using `$html.getElementById("YY")`

Comment: It did not work unfortunatelly so I decided to use childNodes to get the child nodes of <div id="XX">.